# How to stop video after ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```html
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

    <section id="top" class="clearfix">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="ml-title" style="margin-bottom: 2em">
            <span class="pull-left top">Watch</span>
            <ul role="tablist" class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#video_1" aria-expanded="false">Video 1</a></li>
                <li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#video_2" aria-expanded="false">Video 2</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#video_3" aria-expanded="false">Video 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="video_1" class="rows tab-pane in fade active">
                <div class="post">
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kJQP7kiw5Fk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="video_2" class="rows tab-pane in fade">
                <div class="post">
                    <<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JGwWNGJdvx8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="video_3" class="rows tab-pane in fade">
                <div class="post">
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/papuvlVeZg8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here I use bootstrap for ajax.
I switch between video and then play. How can I stop play when switching between videos.
Or is there any other way to ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery or javascript. I used jQuery and below code will stop the video from playing while switching between tabs. But please assign some classname for ul to differentiate from other ul elements

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('ul > li').click(function() {
        var $activeVideoIframe = $('.tab-content').find('.active').find('iframe')
        var playingVideoSrc = $activeVideoIframe.attr('src');
        $activeVideoIframe.attr('src', '');
        $activeVideoIframe.attr('src', playingVideoSrc);
    });
});
```

Here is the working example - https://jsfiddle.net/q28h3gb4/